# Parsing PDF that has been downloaded from internet

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

---

I have searched questions about this topic on stackoverflow. They really helped me but I stuck again.

My problem is that I need do write a method that downloads pdf from a site like (www.example.com/abc.pdf) and then I want to read the output.  I don't want to save this file, just read in system out.  I don't need to put bytes to fileoutputstream.  I tried to cast bytes to char to get characters ( it can be dumbest solution ).  But I got unknown characters.  Any idea or am I understood it in a wrong way?

Here is the code and its output:

```
String textlink="http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf";// it comes from main class

public String HtmlTest(String textLink) throws IOException{

        StringBuilder sd=new StringBuilder();
        URL link=new URL(textLink);
        URLConnection urlConn = link.openConnection();

         BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try
        {

            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            in.read(data, 0, 1024);
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {

            if(j%100==0){
            sd.append((char)data[j]+"\n"); // i used this for making readable text
            }
            else{
            sd.append((char)data[j]);
            }

        }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
        return sd.toString();

    }
```

---

Output

run:

```
%
PDF-1.3
%ￇ￬ﾏﾢ
7 0 obj
<</Length 8 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
xﾜﾭY[ﾓￛﾶ￮ﾳ&?BoNf,,q%￠ﾼ4￞x&ﾞ6ﾩﾛlￓ
ﾗﾼ￐ﾽￋZeﾑ￲f￻￫￻ﾁ
```

Comment: Try specifying the encoding used while reading.

Comment: I would consider looking into IText: http://itextpdf.com/

But please be mindful that their license is a bit restrictive.

Comment: Problem is that PDF is not a plain text file (.txt): it has a well defined and quite structured format. You'll definitely need a library to extract text from PDF _in a clean way_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get very far trying to read a .pdf file as though it were basically a text file.  For starters, the "text" is in a compressed binary format; there are other issues you'll probably also have to deal with.

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Use a Java .pdf library like [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

IMHO>.